# How to make use of existing JSP template provided by eclipse in my own wizard to generate JSP file?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I have my own file creation wizard, where in I accept file name from user. on Finish of wizard I want to generate a JSP using templates provided by eclipse or those which are set from preferences. How can i achieve this ? plz help.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`NewJSPTemplatesWizardPage`](http://eclipsesrc.appspot.com/jsrcs/org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui/src/org/eclipse/jst/jsp/ui/internal/wizard/NewJSPTemplatesWizardPage.java.html) and [`NewJSPWizard`](http://eclipsesrc.appspot.com/jsrcs/org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui/src/org/eclipse/jst/jsp/ui/internal/wizard/NewJSPWizard.java.html).

The actual code to retrieve the templates is

```
TemplateStore fTemplateStore = JSPUIPlugin.getDefault().getTemplateStore();
fTemplateStore.getTemplates(TemplateContextTypeIdsJSP.NEW);
```